# How to use react-select-table's rows as options to react-select's input field

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-bootstrap-table

I have an input field that should accept multiple inputs from options that are already set. - This input field needs to appear like tag input fields so I used the React-select library:
[image]

The set options are going to come from a react-bootstrap-table so I disabled the built-in dropdown in the react-select input field.

The problem is that I cannot remove the selected items by deselecting the row from the react-bootstrap-table.[image]
I think I am doing something wrong on how I'm passing the values between the input field and the table but can't figure it out.

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-wave-6s9ipo?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you try to compare two Objects, however **there is no generic means to determine that an object is equal to another**.
You could `JSON.stringify` them both and compare but thats not reliable way.

Instead, you can filter the array by object key, lets say `label`.
In this case, your function should look like this:

```
const setSelected = (row: any, isSelect: any, rowIndex: any, e: any) => {
    if (isSelect) {
        setSelectProducts([...selectedProducts, row]);
    } else {
        const newArray = selectedProducts.filter(
            (item) => item.label !== row.label
        );
        setSelectProducts(newArray);
    }
};
```

Here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-sun-c303pk?file=/src/App.tsx:1260-1359) to preview

@Edit

If you wanna do something onClear

```
onChange={(selectedOption, triggeredAction) => {
  if (triggeredAction.action === 'clear') {
    // Clear happened
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, @Damian Busz. Is there also an easy way to unselect the item in the react-bootstrap-table from the react-select input? I'm not sure if there's an attribute in react-select to customize the clear button

Comment: I have edited my original answer
If the answer helps can you mark it as accepted answer? thank you @L.Diaz